# Use chrome.storage.sync API in PWA

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-storage, progressive-web-apps, google-chrome-storage

I am working on creating my first PWA. I created a Chrome Extension in the past, and used the chrome.storage.sync API to store data in the cloud (it's stored using Google Drive TMK).

```
 chrome.storage.sync.set({ [key]: val }, function() {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      reject(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  });
```

is there a way to use this API when creating PWAs? This API is documented here:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

it might be possible to use the Google Drive REST API to store key/value data but I cant figure out how yet:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/appdata

Comment: If a user signs into Chrome, it would be nice to sync data across devices, that's what I am trying to accomplish, but with a PWA instead of Chrome Extension.

Comment: Nope. Chrome API is for chrome extensions and chrome apps, not PWA.

Comment: yeah, is there a way to use Google Drive as a db somehow?